# n by n matrix change to 1 dimension with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, matrix, list-comprehension

I have a 3x3 matrix, like ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
I want to change this matrix to [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] with python list comprehension, not numpy_c

Answer (score 1):

here is a single-liner:

```
[mat[i][j] for i in range(len(mat)) for j in range(len(mat[0]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
output = []
for i in matrix:
    for j in i:
        output.append(j)
print(output)
```

Here is something better:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
output = []
for i in matrix:
    output.extend(i)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
x =np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
y=[]
for i in x:
    for e in i:
        y.append(e)
print(y)
```

x= your matrix
y= empty list for appending items.

Fisrt for loop iterating rows, inner for loop is iterating elements and adding to our empty list.